# Searching within a folder structure in Core Data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, predicate

I have a Core Data model consisting of folders and items. A folder may contain either subfolders or items. Each item has a "Folder" relationship. Each folder has a "Parent" relationship (which may be nil). Inverse relationships are also defined.

Say I have the following structure:

```
FOLDER 1
  SUBFOLDER 1.1
    ITEM 1 = "abc"
  SUBFOLDER 1.2
    SUBFOLDER 1.2.1
      ITEM 2 = "abc"
FOLDER 2
  ITEM 3 = "abc"
```

What I would like to do is to search for "abc" in FOLDER 1 only, so that I'll get ITEM 1 and ITEM 2 but not ITEM 3.

Is there a predicate that I can use for this, or do I have to filter the results myself after I get them from Core Data?

Answer (score 1):

Can you search for your item's parent name if it contains "FOLDER 1", that will cover all subfolders of FOLDER 1, but not FOLDER 2.

See here for how to create an NSPredicate for string comparisons.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: The parent name doesn't necessarily contain the text "FOLDER 1". The names given are just an example. Think of FOLDER 1 as FOOD, SUBFOLDER 1.1 as VEGETABLES, SUBFOLDER 1.2 as MEAT, SUBFOLDER 1.2.1 as POULTRY.